# How to ensure existing only one coroutine of a specific kind

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

in my class I have a method that fetches the website (visible below).

I've noticed that other methods that use this method, can lead to the opening of multiple requests to one site (when one request is pending self._page is still none).

How can I avoid it?

I mean when there is another call to _get_page but one is pending, just return a future from the first one and don't repeat a page request

```
async def _get_page(self) -> HtmlElement:
        if self._page is None:
            async with self._get_session().get(self._url) as page:
                self._page = lxml.html.document_fromstring(await page.text())
        return self._page
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I avoid [multiple requests]?

You could use an [`asyncio.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock):

```
saync def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    self._page_lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def _get_page(self) -> HtmlElement:
    async with self._page_lock:
        if self._page is None:
            async with self._get_session().get(self._url) as page:
                self._page = lxml.html.document_fromstring(await page.text())
    return self._page
```

Comment: This is certainly a simpler solution than mine. By the way, this generates: `AttributeError: module 'lxml' has no attribute 'html'` (the OP's original code).

Comment: I took the OP's request at face value and returned a Future, which doesn't block.

Comment: @Booboo I'm not sure what you mean by "returned a Future" - your `_get_page` certainly appears to await the future and return the actual result, just like mine. (Note that you could simply `return await future` because awaiting a future immediately evaluates to its result.) Your code duplicates the functionality already resent in asyncio synchronization devices like `Lock` or `Event`, which [track a list of waiters](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/68526fe258da8c01196fd7cf48e8e5f1280bf8fd/Lib/asyncio/locks.py#L203) in a very similar way.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Python 3.8 and jupyter notebook**

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from lxml import html


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._url = 'https://www.google.com'
        self._page = None
        self._futures = []
        self._working = False
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()


    async def _close(self):
        if self._session:
            session = self._session
            self._session = None
            await session.close()

    def _get_session(self):
        return self._session

    async def _get_page(self):
        if self._page is None:
            if self._working:
                print('will await current page request')
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                future = loop.create_future()
                self._futures.append(future)
                return await future
            else:
                self._working = True
            session = self._get_session()
            print('making url request')
            async with session.get(self._url) as page:
                print('status =', page.status)
                print('making page request')
                self._page = html.document_fromstring(await page.text())
                print('Got page text')
                for future in self._futures:
                    print('setting result to awaiting request')
                    future.set_result(self._page)
                self._futures = []
                self._working = False
        return self._page


async def main():
    futures = []
    m = MyClass()
    futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(m._get_page()))
    futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(m._get_page()))
    futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(m._get_page()))
    results = await asyncio.gather(*futures)
    for result in results:
        print(result[0:80])
    await m._close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    #await main() # In jupyter notebook and iPython
```

Note that on Windows 10 I have seen at termination:

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

See https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324

Comment: I've updated the answer to address Python 3.8, Jupyter Notebook and some spurious errors you could see on Windows 10. A little feedback would be appreciated.